# How does the scid opening trainer work

Tags: training, scid

I'm trying to use the opening trainer in scid. I've set up a filtered database of master games in a particular opening, as [described in the wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/scid/wiki/TheOpeningTrainer/). I was expecting some kind of interactive experience from there but, when I start the opening trainer, it just cycles through the moves in the database then offers me a report. What am I missing?

Comment: Any ideas? I also would like an answer to this.

Comment: My recommendation would be to find a different way to do it, is that among the possibilities?

Answer (score 4):

I'll give instructions for Scid 4.6.4. With this setup, I haven't seen any issues where it moves both sides:

1. Create a database of openings you want to study. Scid will select randomly from all variations of all games, so make sure you want to train on everything in that database. Open the database switcher and make sure your desired openings database is selected.
2. Database > Maintenance > Maintenance Window (Ctrl + M). You should see your database name at the top. Next to the name of your database, click the image to the right of "Type Icon:" and select either "Openings for White" or "Openings for Black". Note that this option decides your selection in step 4. Let's say you select "Openings for Black"; the only option you can select in step 4 is to play as Black. If you want to play White, you'll need to either reclassify the database in the Maintenance Window or rotate the board (after you've selected to play black) and it will let you play the White pieces. "Openings for either color" allows you to select playing both sides in the Openings Trainer, but from what I've seen it'll just play one side anyway.

[image]

3. If desired, add additional flags for White or Black openings here in the Maintenance Window. I don't think this does anything for the Opening Trainer.
4. You may need to restart Scid. Play > Training > Openings. Customize your options (such as which side you want to play) and hit Continue. Play a move and Scid should play the other side if you've selected either White or Black. Once it displays "End of variation" in the window that pops up, you can use the arrow keys to move back to move 1 (or select move 1 in the Notation) and it will randomly select another variation. If you're ever stuck on a move, click "Display candidate moves" in the pop-up and below that button it will show your options.

Comment: Should I create one database, or two databases (one each for my white and black repertoire)?

Comment: A lot of us have our opening databases stored as masks rather than games because it handles translations transparently.  You might want to add that case to your answer.

Comment: @user1583209 if you'd like to study one side at a time, then yes you could make two separate databases.

Comment: @Qudit I'm still fairly new to Scid so I've never heard of masks. Could you write up a quick how-to for doing Opening Training with those?

Comment: "Create a database of openings you want to study." I have a .bin file, but I can't tell how to make a SCID "database" out of it. Thank you for the pointers!

Answer (score 3):

The opening trainer can only be understood and used by the programmers themselves it's how I would describe it, the options are not user friendly.  So I suggest that you click the List Window then choose the game you want to train, make the first move, if you want to practice White, then click the replay button, a little on top of board, a forward triangle icon, then just move ahead for the White moves because if not then the program will auto play the White moves for you.  You can set the replay move speed on Options... Moves... Autoplay Time Delay...

Comment: I am a programmer, and I'm struggling the second morning in a row. I keep getting "All problems solved" message. No idea how to reset it.